# Why is my codes having error 00049 Bad Bind Variable

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, unique-constraint

```
create or replace  trigger addDate
before insert or update on Employee
for each row
begin
    for EmployeeRec in
(
    select * from employee
)
loop
    if (EmployeeRec.DateLimit > sysdate) then
        raise_application_error (-20001, 'You are only allowed to insert once a day, please try again 
        tomorrow');
end if;
end loop EmployeeRec;
:NEW.DateLimit := sysdate + 1;
end;
/
show errors;
```

> Need to be able to insert a record for a day only. Any other records must wait till the next day
> There is PLS 00049 ERROR at New.DateLimit

Answer (score 0):

Maybe column name is not DateLimit, but Date_Limit.

Comment: If you need one record for oner employee per day then you can have a unique constraint  and a date updated/inserted column and check for that ? What happens if you receive 10 rows for an employee one one day, then what is the  process to insert it ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am following you correctly, you want to allow just one record per day, as defined by column `date_limit`.

You don't need a trigger for this. One option uses a computed column and a unique constraint.

```
create table employee (
    employee_id  int primary key,
    name         varchar2(100),
    date_limit   date default sysdate,
    day_limit    date generated always as (trunc(date_limit)) unique
);
```

`day_limit` is a computed column, that contains the date portion of `date_limit` (with the time portion removed). A `unique` constraint is set on this column, so two rows cannot have `date_limit`s that belong to the same day.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5f98ea92f8dac92575cca2c8e88b2bb7)**

Comment: As in that is the question! The assignment states to create a trigger hahaha